# Change binary number to 2C notation

Tags: c++, binary

I have to create function which will let me change binary number to binary number in 2C notation.

So.. I have something like:

```
string changeTo2C(int number){
int temp=number;
if(number<0)
    number*=-1;
string binary=changeToBin(number);  //number changed to binary

//complement to 8bits
binary=complementBits(binary); 

if(temp<0)
{
    //negate
    for(int i=0; i<howManyBits; i++)
    {
        if(binary[i]=='0')
            binary[i]='1';
        else
            binary[i]='0';
    }
    //add bit (1)
    binary=addBit(binary); //HERE
}
return binarna;
```

}

And I don't know how to add this last bit in this number. (We have to add one bit to whole number after negate binary number to change it to 2C notation).

I tried do it like:

```
for(int i=howManyBits-1; i>=0; i--)
{
    if(binary[i]=='0')
    {
        binary[i]=='1';
        break;

    }
    else
    {
        binary[i]='0';
    }
}
```

that's not working and I don't have more ideas to solve that problem.

Could you give me advice or paste some code?
Greetings,
Kamil.

Comment: Maybe you could add it while it's still an int. That is before you run the `changeToBin()` function.

Comment: Can you post input/output results? In addition, it won't work for number=0 because you don't add bit if the number is 0, since it's negation is all 1, and it should become 0 again when adding bit.

Comment: i.e. 74(10)=01001010(2),  −74(10)=10110110(U2), I am handling this 0 in changeToBin function.

Comment: Add bit to int? How?

Answer (score -1):

I wrote an example in comments:
 74(10)=01001010(2), −74(10)=10110110(U2)

this is how should it work:
we have: 01001010(2) -> negate 10110101(2) -> +1bit (+00000001) = 10110110(U2)

//EDIT

I actually made it :)
Maybe it is not the best solution, but it works.
That's my function to add 1 bit after negate number.

```
string addBit(string binary)
{
    string bit="00000001";
    for(int i=howManyBites-1;i>=0;i--)
{
    if(binary[i]=='0' && bit[i]=='1'){
        binary[i]='1';
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        if(binary[i]=='1' && bit[i]=='1')
        {
            binary[i]='0';
            bit[i-1]='1';
        }
        else if(binary[i]=='1' && bit[i]=='0')
        {
            binary[i]='1';
            break;
        }
    }
}
return binary;
}
```

Comment: This should be an edit to the question, not an answer.